# How to detect if client is still connected to SignalR in the Client Side

Tags: angular, signalr

I can detect if a client has diconnected from the server. But my problem is; how would my client know if it is still connected to the SignalR server.

I have this code in the client side to connect to the server. When I am connected, I change my status to connected. But if I close my SignalR server and I immediately get an error like so:

> zone.js:3243 GET
> http://localhost:9090/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22apphub%22%7D%5D&_=1563774410720
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I can actually use this to notify my client that I am not connected to the server anymore but I don't know where to get that. Please see my code below on how I connect:

```
public initializeSignalRConnection(): void {
    this.connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:9090');
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('appHub');

    this.proxy.on('clientPipeline', serverMessage =>
      this.onMessageReceived(serverMessage)
    );

    this.proxy.on('connectionMessage', serverMessage =>
      this.onConnection(serverMessage)
    );

    this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
      this.broadcastMessage();
    });
}
```

this.connection.start() only happens when SignalR server is running. But if it is not running, I would like to get the error message.

I was thinking on something like this:

```
this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
      this.broadcastMessage();
    }, (err_ => {
         "CONNECTION ERROR"
});
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the connection for a change in the stateChanged and display whatever info/popup/modal/etc you like to inform your user.

```
    $.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (status_value) {
    if (status_value.newState == 0) { //Attempting a new connection
    }
    else if (status_value.newState == 1) { //Established a connection
    }
    else if (status_value.newState == 2) { //Attempting reconnect
    }
    else if (status_value.newState == 4) { //Connection lost
    }
});
```